# Cannot Authenticate via connected app

Tags: salesforcedx, connected-apps, cicd

I am trying to setup a basic ci/cd pipeline and following a guide i found online that suggests authenticating via a connected app. I have created the connected app and uploaded the server.crt

when i try to authenticate using:
sfdx force:auth:jwt:grant --clientid 3Mxxxxxx --jwtkeyfile NewCerts/server.key --username xx@gmail.com --instanceurl https://login.salesforce.com, i am getting the following error:

Error (1): We encountered a JSON web token error, which is likely not an issue with Salesforce CLI. Here’s the error: Error authenticating with JWT.
Errors encountered:
client identifier invalid
client identifier invalid
client identifier invalid

I have checked and rechecked the consumer key and its okay. I have tried with changing the instance URL to my org URL but getting the same error.
I use a Mac so unsure if that requires any additional steps. I have also noticed on VSCode that I lose my default Org connection as soon as i execute the test command. I have googled 'client identifier invalid' error but have not been able to resolve.

Would appreciate any help

Comment: Did you try by using the exact instanceUrl instead of login.salesforce.com ?

Comment: If you want to be sure to create the connected app the good way, you can try https://sfdx-hardis.cloudity.com/salesforce-ci-cd-setup-auth/